# Pushing a gitlab release

Tags: magit, gitlab

Is there a way to push via Magit, so that the push will automatically produce a release in GitLab?

For example: I prepare my files, open the Magit status buffer, stage the file via <kbd>s</kbd>, commit the file via <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>, enter my commit message and press <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd>.

Next I define a new, annotated and signed tag via <kbd>t</kbd><kbd>-a</kbd><kbd>-s</kbd> enter the version number<kbd>RET</kbd> enter the version message<kbd>RET</kbd>.

Now I can start to push everything to the remote Gitlab <kbd>P</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> enter the previous defined version number<kbd>RET</kbd> and <kbd>P</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>.

After having typed so, the Magit status buffer shows me, that it had pushed the new commit with the new tag.  Gitlab also has the new tag with the version number and its version message.  But it has not created a release of this commit/push.

To build the release, I have to go to the tags page of my Gitlab project and edit the tag in question.  After having added and stored a release note, the release is finally build by Gitlab.

Is there a way, to enter the release note while definig the new tag or pushing from Magit?

Comment: What is a "release" from a Git-only perspective?  If the answer is "nothing; this is a Gitlab-specific concept" then Magit possibly can't do this (but [Forge](https://github.com/magit/forge) might be able to).

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/ seems relevant if you need to raise a feature request.

Comment: Thank you @phils It seems to be a Gitlab specific thing to be.  I will have a look at the Forge documents.

Comment: I tried to implement `Magit-Forge` for Gitlab but got stuck in contacting the server, see my [new question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/70259/setup-magit-forge-to-connect-gitlab), but reading from the Manual, this will be the solution to my question

Comment: Hopefully you will be able to post an answer to your own question here, after the new problem is resolved.

Comment: If I get an answer, I will.  Lets hope the best.